# Exercise with Data: day,month,year

Tags: c++

Please help with the task, it sounds like this:

Create class with fields Date: day, month, year; Function-method 1 of data processing: Increase year by 1; Function method 2 of data processing: reduce date by 2 days; +

Implement the following methods in the class:
1. The default constructor
2. Constructor overload with parameters
3. Memory Destructor (with Object Destruction Notification)
4. Data processing functions
5. The function of forming a string with information about the object

Here is the code I was trying to make:

```
class Date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
public:
     Date();
     Date(y, m, d);
     bool operator==(const Date &other) const;
     void setYear(y);
     void setMonth(m);
     void setDay(d);
     //...
};
Date::Date() {
     year = 0;
     month = 0;
     day = 0;
}
Date::Date(y, m, d) {
     year = y;
     month = m;
     day = d;
```

Comment: what is the problem? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: We generally don't write code for you here at StackOverflow. If you have a question about a bug in your implementation of a requirement we can help with that but you need to explain your problem and show the code you have a problem with. Also your code must actually make an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I have problems with this task. I'm new to c ++. I do not know how to properly handle the data processing functions for these dates

Comment: You need to narrow down your request to 1 specific problem you are trying to solve and show your attempt to solve that 1 problem. We are not here to write a full solution to your homework assignment.

Comment: "how to properly handle the data processing functions for these dates" there are no data processing functions in the code you posted. I dont want to sound rude, but if you have a problem with doing your homework you better ask you tutor or co-students, here at least you should explain detailed what prevents you from solving it

Comment: Your functions and constructors **must** know what type of data will you send them, which means your declarations `void setYear(y);`, ..., `Date::Date(y, m, d)` are wrong and should consist of type and variable name `void setYear (int y)` and `Date::Date(int y, int m, int d)`. Also think about changing data in default constructor, as date 0/0/0 is not valid and you would probably like to store only correct dates inside the structure.

Comment: You should look up *initialization list* in your favorite C++ reference.